# Share MySql volume between 2 containers

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to share the same database for 5 containers. These are my commands:

Contaniner 1:

```sh
docker run -p 2021:80 \
-v C:\xxx\xxx\xxx/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
--name=contaner_1 --privileged=true  \
image /usr/sbin/init
```

Container 2:

```sh
docker run -p 2022:80 \
-v C:\xxx\xxx\xx/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
--name=contaner_2 --privileged=true  \
image /usr/sbin/init
```

I really appreciate your recommendations.

Comment: Do you need all containers access all databases? Or each container should access one database only?

Comment: Duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215280/running-two-mysql-servers-that-use-the-same-data-directory ?

Comment: Don't. Each MySQL instance needs to be the only one accessing and changing the data files associated with it's databases. If you absolutely need multiple instances with the same data, you should look into replicating the data.

Comment: Those commands look odd to me; why would a database container need to run as `--privileged`, why would it publish port 80 but not port 3306, and why would you need to spell out `init` as the command to run when you launch it?

Comment: @Saeed The idea is that all containers access the same database.

Comment: I'm agree with @davidmaze too. You also can use `docker-compose`. Did you try that? There's no need to share the volume. I think there's better approach with docker compose.

Comment: @BertC According to your link, what I want is not a good idea. :(

Comment: Do you want 5 Applications (each running in its own container) all access the same database? Or do you want 5 Database-Containers (each running MySQL image) accessing all the same database files. If the first option, then a docker-compose network should work best. If the second option: Please don't do that, look at MySQL replication instead.

Comment: @BertC yes, is the second option. Ok y i'm going to read abaut " MySQL replication instead"